# PEStudio unable to analyze certain malware samples - grayed out sections with '(wait)', why?

Tags: malware, malware-detection

I had several malware samples and used PEStudio for static analysis. Some samples worked very well, but other  samples that PEStudio could not analyze it.

Very few sections in PEstudio are grayed out and had "(wait)" beside it ( example is this string section and many other ones )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifq65.png)

I tried reinstall it but still not work

Answer (score 0):

Just wait a little bit, generally, it takes time as there will be too many things to analyze.